# Highlight a cell based on adjacent value only if it is greater than plus or minus 30 difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a row of 20 numbers and am trying to create a rule that would highlight any cell that pluses up by 30 or more; or decreases by 30 or more compared to the adjacent cells value.

[Highlight based on adjacent cell value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtwZ.png)
in the photo, you see Row 1 contains a standard time stamp. Row 2, is where the actual value would be entered every hour. B1 has a value of 10, C2 has a value of 50, which is +/- 30 different than B1, therefore it would auto highlight red. D1 is not more than +/-30 compared to C2, so will not highlight. Lastly, F2 is more than +/-30 compared to E2, so it will auto highlight. hope this helps. thanks

Comment: 10 40, which will it highlight? 40 10, which will it highlight? You might want to take a look at conditional formatting

Comment: Would be great to post some sample data with desired output

Comment: For better understanding plzz [edit] your post & add some sample data will help us to fix it in batter way !!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say row 1 (A1-I1) are the cells you want to format.
Start at cell B1:

Home> Conditional Formatting> New Rule> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Format values where this formula is true

```
=ABS(B$1-A$1)>=30
```

which means highlight if the absolute value (if its a negative number it becomes a positive number. eg. -30 becomes 30) is greater than or equal to 30

then set the format by clicking Format...

then change the Applies to so it goes all the way to your last column:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3VMi.png

Here is what you should get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3kBy.png

Comment: Nice one you get +10 ,, keep posting ☺

Comment: !! that looks like what i am looking for, i will try that. thank you